# Magento- admin pannel menu not visible on menu bar

Tags: magento-1.9

I installed magento 1.9 version on localhost, code downloaded from live server.
In the admin panel I can only see the 3 menu's **sales** , **catalog** and **reports**.

Rest of the menu is not visible like system menu and other configuration menu.

I am new to magneto so please suggest me where can I change to see all the menu in the admin panel.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your admin user has permissions for all modules. Check your user group

Comment: I think I already I ahve permission allowed for admin user in DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new user and login from that particular user which have full permission. Run below given code in magento root for creating new user:

**Newuser.php**

```
<?php
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {
    echo $mageFilename." was not found";
    exit;
}
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::app();

try {
    //create new user by providing details below
    $user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')
        ->setData(array(
            'username'  => 'admin1',
            'firstname' => 'John',
            'lastname'  => 'Doe',
            'email'     => 'vignesh@securenext.in',
            'password'  => 'admin123',
            'is_active' => 1
        ))->save();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

try {
    //create new role
    $role = Mage::getModel("admin/roles")
            ->setName('Inchoo')
            ->setRoleType('G')
            ->save();

    //give "all" privileges to role
    Mage::getModel("admin/rules")
            ->setRoleId($role->getId())
            ->setResources(array("all"))
            ->saveRel();

} catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error while saving role.';
    exit;
}

try {
    //assign user to role
    $user->setRoleIds(array($role->getId()))
        ->setRoleUserId($user->getUserId())
        ->saveRelations();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

echo 'Admin User sucessfully created!<br /><br /><b>THIS FILE WILL NOW TRY TO DELETE ITSELF, BUT PLEASE CHECK TO BE SURE!</b>';
@unlink(__FILE__);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you need to go to your FTP server and find the folder modules under:

/public_html/app/etc/modules

Here you have to enable the disabled modules again ->

Open the specific xml-module-file, in your favorite notepad editor e.g:

Amasty_Base.xml

-> Find the line false

Change false > true and SAVE and upload file back to server.

Repeat this on all the disabled files and empty cache and try login/logout.

Let me know how is works.